# filtering data from a csv file and storing it in a mysql database using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am a new intern and new to .net and i have been given the task of filtering data from csv file and save to Microsoft SQL Server susing VB.NET,so far I haven't seen a straightforward answer,anyone who can help?...,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can import CSV into SQL-Server directly via [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

If you need/want to use .NET you can use a CSV-reader like [**this**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) to read the csv-file. Then you can use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to import it into database very efficiently.

Here is an article about it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439843/Handling-BULK-Data-insert-from-CSV-to-SQL-Server

VB.NET:

```
Using conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
    Try
        Using file As New StreamReader(filename)
            Dim csv As New CsvReader(file, True, "|"c) ' change to your separator '
            Dim copy As New SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction)
            copy.DestinationTableName = tablename
            copy.WriteToServer(csv)
            transaction.Commit()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        transaction.Rollback()
    End Try
End Using ' closes also the connection '
```

Comment: Thanks Tim....,I fairly new,my manager has given me a large csv file that I am supposed to select some columns read by looping through their data line by line and then insert the data to another table in a Microsoft Server,I suggested the bulk Copy method of inserting but he insisted that is for importing not reading....,

Comment: @VincentMacharia: You can also use the VB.NET `TextfieldParser` class to read and parse the csv-file. Of course are are many ways to do it, i have just shown the most efficient approach using `SqlBulkCopy`. Another option is to use a loop over the lines in the file and a simple `SqlCommand` to insert the records.

Comment: Thanks alot I will still use SqlBulkCopy. Its better and I can understand it more.assist appreciated.